# Alexa unable to link skill - We were unable to link skillname at this time

Tags: oauth-2.0, authorization, alexa-skills-kit

When I try account linking from Alexa web app, I get error 'unable to link your skill'. following is my work progress.

1. Alexa app is able to open my authentication url.
2. I am able to authorize and provide authorization code with redirect uri.
3. Alexa fails in this step to link with my skill. It say's 'Unable to link
   your skill'.
4. It is not even calling my api for access and refresh token

   Redirect URI Format https://layla.amazon.com/api/skill/link/**********?state=A2SAAEAEAuglqkkHrQ2dx9KcQKveKgBsNCS0Ijx0oKQfUmcMbaXm6nc7rfQEaLns1iv3aRue6PqvYjr8yVzJcaCtC8OPVm6tCfbT-9lOYh0VPujQwp0JRa9-gJpKqN4Ny0eCIMFvdYeQT2SsII-oC8siTPxF5UNhXR2-No4VqhqelOZHHNe5BXs91roaLtAAtJrv9vb-W5c3QSSZpFuXRFopJHmtYVc4so5dIyG09aU7CEcTCybqQ735chV9BwLR6LvYxrniUERhR8-IyPmJcV60_FJ-pOVEAiHOl4jEhZG08KvoIFa1SELf8WLgmbIbdb4a14EAqEtNv5nDJaST9m12MF_EM8j5De4MJmMssncG3AVcRzK_j4qSSdaZuoetQ-QYemb2R0QPh0zssGeT9DMdszkSCWo4krA5eCXNeOEmp4JNCJjwThuT4vwhoz0rFu8Pdz5SaCzwQ1ushRTYLwun4-asdn682C8Dml52ifQ&code=******************************************

I have gone through my forums about the same, but couldn't find what exactly the issue is. Can any one tell me why its not calling my api with provided auth code?

Comment: Were you able to figure this out ? I have the exact same issue on my hands. Thanks

Comment: I am also facing same issue.  "We were unable to link betty at this time"

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am getting the same issue 'Linking unsuccessful'

Comment: Yes.. my referesh and access token generation API from access code was having problem in it's header. Kindly check if you're using proper header at server side. Please refer Alexa developer documentation for more details.

Comment: @Aram Tchekrekjian : please share the steps you have followed for aws auth

Comment: I managed to make it work successfully. Actually, I had multiple issues:
 
1- My Identity Server was changing the **state** upon authorizing the user. The state is initiated by Alexa itself, so it must remain the same all the way until it reaches the redirect_url provided by amazon.
2- The Login URL was published on a server with invalid certificate (development server). The account linking process must be done through https with a valid public certificate.

Comment: Some notes:

- The testing must happen only via Alexa skill account linking. You cannot test directly through the browser. The process should be like >> Install Alexa App -> Open your Skill -> Press 'Enable Account Linking' -> Your login URL will appear -> Users will enter their credentials -> Alexa Will show the success message
- The token endpoint must return the access token in a proper json format
`{"access_token": "[an access token]", "expires_in": 21599, "refresh_token": "[a refresh token]"}`
- The token endpoint must return the access token **within 4.5 seconds**

Comment: @Shan, Do you have solution it? Please look at this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56070119/amazon-alexa-skill-we-were-unable-to-link-xxxx-at-this-time-and-with-401-unaut

Comment: What I had to do that I didn't realize was the request to the Access Token URI from amazon is a `POST` not a `GET`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use Amazon Fire HD8 to link MEROSS Switch after getting only cannot link messages with anything else I tried.